# Fetch localStorage values to other page using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I am storing the values in localStorage and the values are getting stored through input[type:hidden] and input[type:text].
JS:

```
$('.proceed_btn').on('click', function() {
  // Blank to start with

  var order = {};

  // Loop through all inputs...
  $('input[type="text"], input[type="hidden"]').each(function() {
    // ...adding their values as properties
    order[this.name] = this.value;
  });

  // Store that object in JSON format
  localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify(order));
});
```

I want to print these value in other page when the user redirects after submitting the form. I am working on ruby currently. There are many products in the website, so the information in the summary page gets rendered according to that. Is there any way to display specific form details in through there id's?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial with `.js.erb` extension eg `_order_partial.js.erb` and retrieve the order object as thus:

```
order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("order"));
// Loop through the object and print out
```

Then you can render the partial in any of the views file you want to use it.